# Associating two item in a list

Tags: python, list

I am comparing two lists for common strings and my code currently works to output items in common from two lists.

list1

```
['5', 'orange', '20', 'apple', '50', 'blender']
```

list2

```
['25', 'blender', '20', 'pear', '40', 'spatula']
```

Here is my code so far:

```
for item1 in list1[1::2]:
    for item2 in list2[1::2]:
        if item1 == item2:
            print(item1)
```

This code would return blender. What I want to do now is to also print the number before the blender in each list to obtain an output similar to:

```
blender, 50, 25
```

I have tried to add two new lines to the for loop but did not have the desired output:

```
for item1 in list1[1::2]:
    for item2 in list2[1::2]:
        for num1 in list1[0::2]:
            for num2 in list2[0::2]:
               if item1 == item2:
                   print(item1, num1, num2)
```

I know now that making for loops is not the answer. Also trying to call item1[-1] does not work. I am new to Python and need some help with this!

Thank you

Comment: This seems like an XY problem.  If that is the kind of output you're looking to get, storing information in lists like that is not going to be the best approach.  It honestly looks like you want a dictionary with words as keys, and the number before them as values

Comment: Take a look at the `enumerate` and `zip` functions

Comment: Is this your special requirement to iterate over list on indexes 1,3,5.... Not on 0,2,4,6.....     Consider if blender comes at index either 0,2,4,6... of any one List   then will it not be considered as common element on lists??

Comment: Why does this have 19 upvotes?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do it in two ways, either stay with lists (Which is more messy):

```
list1 = ['5', 'orange', '20', 'apple', '50', 'blender']
list2 = ['25', 'blender', '20', 'pear', '40', 'spatula']
for item1 in list1[1::2]:
  for item2 in list2[1::2]:
    if item1 == item2:
       item_to_print = item1
       print(item1, ",", end="")
       for index in range(len(list1)):
           if list1[index] == item1:
               print(list1[index - 1], ",", end="")
       for index in range(len(list2)):
           if list2[index] == item1:
               print(list2[index - 1])
```

or the better way (in my opinion) with dictionary:

```
dict1 = {'apple': '20', 'blender': '50', 'orange': '5'}
dict2 = {'blender': '25', 'pear': '20', 'spatula': '40'}
for item in dict1:
   if item in dict2:
       print(item, ",", dict1[item], ",", dict2[item])
```

Both will output:

```
>> blender , 50 , 25
```

Comment: Why not use `for i in range(1,len(list),2) `so you don't have to iterate another time to see the value?

Comment: `dict1.get(key, "default-value")` can be useful too *if you want to get a default value if the key is not present*.

Answer (score 13):

You're approaching this problem with the wrong Data Structure.  You shouldn't keep this data in lists if you're doing lookups between the two.  Instead, it would be much easier to use a dictionary here.

***Setup***

You can use `zip` to create these two dictionaries:

```
a = ['5', 'orange', '20', 'apple', '50', 'blender']
b = ['25', 'blender', '20', 'pear', '40', 'spatula']

dct_a = dict(zip(a[1::2], a[::2]))
dct_b = dict(zip(b[1::2], b[::2]))
```

This will leave you with these two dictionaries:

```
{'orange': '5', 'apple': '20', 'blender': '50'}
{'blender': '25', 'pear': '20', 'spatula': '40'}
```

---

This makes every part of your problem easier to solve.  For example, to find common keys:

```
common = dct_a.keys() & dct_b.keys()
# {'blender'}
```

And to find all the values matching each common key:

```
[(k, dct_a[k], dct_b[k]) for k in common]
```

Output:

```
[('blender', '50', '25')]
```

Comment: Thank you, I haven't gone over dictionaries yet in my class but this does work!

Answer (score 5):

I think you'd be better suited using dictionaries for this problem..

```
dict1 = {'orange': 5, 'apple': 20, 'blender': 50}
dict2 = {'blender': 25, 'pear': 20, 'spatula': 40}
```

so to get the outputs you want

```
>>dict1['blender']
50
>>dict2['blender']
25
```

So if you want to get the number of blenders from each dictionary in the format you want, you can really just use

```
print("blender, "+str(dict1['blender'])+", "+str(dict2['blender']))
```

To take this one step further and output based on what's in `dict1` and `dict2`

```
for i in dict1.keys(): #dict1.keys() is essentially a list with ['orange','apple','blender']
    if i in dict2.keys(): #same deal, but different items in the list
        print(str(i)+", "+str(dict1[i])+", "+str(dict2[i])) #this outputs items that are in BOTH lists
    else:
        print(str(i)+", "+str(dict1[i])) #this outputs items ONLY in dict1
for i in dict2.keys():
    if i not in dict1.keys(): #we use not since we already output the matching in the previous loop
        print(str(i)+", "+str(dict2[i])) #this outputs items ONLY in dict2
```

Outputs:

```
orange, 5
apple, 20
blender, 50, 25
pear, 20
spatula, 40
```

Answer (score 5):

with `enumerate` you can solve your problem:

```
list1 = ['5', 'orange', '20', 'apple', '50', 'blender']
list2 = ['25', 'blender', '20', 'pear', '40', 'spatula']



for n1, item1 in enumerate(list1[1::2]):
    for n2, item2 in enumerate(list2[1::2]):
        if item1 == item2:
            print(list1[n1*2], list2[n2*2], item1)
```

enumerate returns a `tuple` where the first element is the count of the iteration, the second the element.
Since `enumerate` is counting the iteration and you're stepping 2, we need to multiply by 2:
`orange` will be the first iteration, so `n1` will be 0, so the previous value is at index `0*2`
`apple` will be in the second iteration, so `n1` will be 1, so the previous value is at index `1*2`
`blender` will be in the third iteration, so `n1` will be 2, so the previousl value is at index `2*2`.

this means that in `for n1, item1 in enumerate(list1[1::2]):` `n1` and `item1` will have this values:

> Iteration 1: n1 = 0, item1 = orange, previous_index = 0*2
>   Iteration 2: n1 = 1, item1 = apple, previous_index = 1*2
>   Iteration 3: n1 = 2, item1 = blender, previous_index = 2*2

same goes for `for n2, item2 in enumerate(list2[1::2]):`:

> Iteration 1: n2 = 0, item2 = blender, previous_index = 0*2
>   Iteration 2: n2 = 1, item2 = pear, previous_index = 1*2
>   Iteration 3: n2 = 2, item2 = spatula, previous_index = 2*2

Comment: This is great, I have to read up on the enumerate function some more but this worked!

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the nouns in your lists are unique (per list), create dictionaries out of your lists first.

```
In [1]: list1 = ['5', 'orange', '20', 'apple', '50', 'blender']
In [2]: list2 = ['25', 'blender', '20', 'pear', '40', 'spatula']
In [3]: 
In [3]: dict1 = dict(reversed(pair) for pair in zip(*[iter(list1)]*2))
In [4]: dict2 = dict(reversed(pair) for pair in zip(*[iter(list2)]*2))
In [5]: 
In [5]: dict1
Out[5]: {'apple': '20', 'blender': '50', 'orange': '5'}
In [6]: dict2
Out[6]: {'blender': '25', 'pear': '20', 'spatula': '40'}
```

This code leverages the `grouper` recipe from the [`itertools` docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes).

Matching two items from your dictionaries is easy as pie.

```
In [7]: key = 'blender'
In [8]: print(key, dict1[key], dict2[key])
blender 50 25
```

You could even build a dictionary that holds the common keys from `dict1` and `dict2` and a list of the values.

```
In [12]: common = dict1.keys() & dict2
In [13]: {c:[dict1[c], dict2[c]] for c in common}
Out[13]: {'blender': ['50', '25']}
```

For an arbitrary number of dicts, you can abstract this further.

```
In [28]: from functools import reduce
In [29]: from operator import and_
In [30]: 
In [30]: dicts = (dict1, dict2)
In [31]: common = reduce(and_, map(set, dicts))
In [32]: {c:[d[c] for d in dicts] for c in common}
Out[32]: {'blender': ['50', '25']}
```

Answer (score 3):

I hope this code will work for you.

```
l1 =['5', 'orange', '20', 'apple', '50', 'blender']
l2 = ['25', 'blender', '20', 'pear', '40', 'spatula']

for list1_item in zip(*[iter(l1)]*2):
    for list2_item in zip(*[iter(l2)]*2):
        if list1_item[1]==list2_item[1]:
            print list1_item[1],list1_item[0],list2_item[0]
```

it will print output

```
blender 50 25
```